# MySQL - return particular row if another joined row has a certain characteristic

Tags: mysql, join

Ok, so I've been working on this query and I'm pretty sure there has to be a better way of doing it rather than my current method which is nesting statement after statement within each other.

Here are my 2 main tables (rewritten quickly so they might not be perfect 'create table' code)

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
    `personid` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `personuuid` VARCHAR(64),
    `flags` INT,
    `last_updated` DATETIME,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(64),
    `last_name` VARCHAR(64)
);

CREATE TABLE `person_status` (
    `person_statusid` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `person_statusesid` INT,
    `personuuid` VARCHAR(64),
    `groupsuuid` VARCHAR(64),
    `start_date` DATE
);
```

Quick description: As you can see an individual person can have (potentially) multiple statuses. The most current status is determined by the start date (whichever has the greatest start date). Each person would also potentially have multiple entries within the person table. (Helps keep track of updating user information) The most up to date information would be the one that has the most recent last_updated value.

What I'm trying to do: I'm trying to get a list of all persons (aka personuuid) such that:

1. The entry that comes back to us has the most recent person status
2. The statuses only show up for a certain groupsuuid (aka filtered by group)
3. We also need additional filtering such that the name is filtered
4. We also need to make sure that flags is equal to 0

Here is the query I am running:

```
SELECT personuuid FROM (
    SELECT personuuid, flags FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT personuuid, flags
            FROM person 
            JOIN (
                SELECT personuuid, t2.person_statusesid FROM (
                        SELECT personuuid, groupsuuid, t1.person_statusesid FROM (
                            SELECT personuuid, groupsuuid, p1.person_statusesid 
                                FROM person_status as p1
                                ORDER BY start_date DESC, person_statusid DESC
                        ) as t1
                        GROUP BY personuuid, groupsuuid
                    ) as t2
                    WHERE groupsuuid='xxxxxxxxxx' AND person_statusesid = X
            ) AS t3 USING (personuuid)
            WHERE  (first_name LIKE '%TEST%' OR last_name LIKE '%TEST%')
            ORDER BY person_statusesid, last_name, first_name, last_updated DESC
        ) as t4
        GROUP BY personuuid
    ) as t5
WHERE flags <> 2;
```

As you can see what I'm doing is joining the person table with a table that orders the person status and then filters by group and statusesid. Then I am taking the two joined tables, filtering by names, and then I'm attempting to grab the most recent person row and making sure that it has the proper flag.

I figured since this seems like a fun puzzle I'd ask you guys to see if someone can come up with a decent solution. I'm not the most expert at these things so I only know more of the basic SQl commands so any advice would be beneficial. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by bringing together the data that I need in one place.  That is, the most recent status record and the most recent person record.  This requires finding the most recent updated date for the two tables and then joining various tables and subqueries together:

```
select ps.*, p.*
from person_status ps join
     (select personuuid, max(last_updated) as maxlu
      from person_status ps
      group by person_status
     ) psm
     on psm.personuuid = psm.personuuid and psm.maxlu = ps.last_updated join
     (select personuuid, max(last_updated) as maxlu
      from person p
      group by personuuid
     ) pm
     on pm.personuuid = ps.personuuid join
     person p
     on pm.personuuid = p.personuuid and pm.maxlu = p.lastupdated
where p.flags = 0 and
      ps.groupsuuid in (<list of groups>) and
      additional filtering;
```

If you are going to have a data structure with an "effective date" (the `lastupdated`) for records, you should consider having an "end date" as well.  This is a bit more work in the update (typically requires a trigger), but it makes queries such as this much, much easier.

EDIT:

Your original query has a fair number of subqueries in it.  In any case, you can rewrite this without the subqueries to simplify matters.  For the following an index on `personuuid, lastupdated` (for both tables) would be needed for performance.

```
select ps.*, p.*
from person_status ps join
     person p
     on ps.personuuid = p.personuuid and
        p.lastupdated = (select p2.lastupdated
                         from person p2
                         where p2.personuuid = p.personuuid
                         order by p2.lastupdated desc
                         limit 1
                        ) and
        ps.lastupdated = (select ps2.lastupdated
                          from person_status ps2
                          where ps2.personuuid = ps.personuuid
                          order by ps2.lastupdated desc
                          limit 1
                         )
where p.flags = 0 and
      ps.groupsuuid in (<list of groups>) and
      additional filtering;
```

In this version, the subqueries are correlated and will turn into index lookups.

Comment: I like this approach, but wouldn't this create slower queries since the first step is in creating large temporary tables? Seems like if the tables were large enough this might become crazy slow no? (Also, having an end_date would be nice, but alas I don't know when a user would choose to update their data =/)